# How do I fix grainy and chewy caramel corn?

Tags: corn, caramel

I made caramel corn and it came out grainy & chewy. How do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome, however I notice that almost before getting a foot in the door you have been edited - don't let this put you off.  In order to try to help you, perhaps if you could tell us how you made your caramel corn.

Comment: @dougal2.0.0 I appreciate you welcoming people, but do keep in mind that there's not really any "however" here. Yes, I edited the question, to make it clearer from the title what's being asked, and to fix an obvious mistake. It's all meant to be improvements, in the interests of helping the OP out, and making it clearer for future readers. The OP is quite welcome to edit further if they wish. This is just how the site works; see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit.

Comment: @Jefromi.  This link might have been more useful to a new member - http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @dougal2.0.0 The link was for you too, since you made a comment about editing. And the OP asked a perfectly fine question, so while it's good to know about the site scope, let's focus on their current question for now.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting your problem down to the two issues.  Though they could be entirely related

1: Grainy
2: Chewy

Let's deal with the first - grainy.  How are you melting your sugar (I am assuming you are using brown), are you adding corn syrup?  Perhaps you have some granules of sugar that are 'un-melted'.  It could be that your corn syrup (if used) is reacting in some way.

Now to the second - chewy.  Try heating your sugar syrup for a little longer.

I hope that this helps.  Below is a great recipe which might help.

[Classic Caramel Corn](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/173309/classic-caramel-corn/)